# How to forward-declare std::set in C++?

Tags: c++, set, std, forward-declaration

To speed up the compiling process, I'm trying to simplify my header file `MyClass.hpp` by forward-declaring STL containers such as std::vector, std::set...

But `std::set` can **NOT** be forward-declared within following codes, while `std::vector` can be.

```
namespace std {
    template<typename T, typename A> class vector;
    template<typename T, typename C, typename A> class set;
};

class MyClass_t {
        void showVector( std::vector<int>& );
        void showSet( std::set<int>& );
}
```

As we know, the header <set> is very long and complicated. If we add `#include <set>` into MyClass.hpp, in fact every translation units that uses MyClass_t have to include implicitly the header <set>. But I think that it's not necessary, because not every translation units using MyClass_t will call `MyClass_t::showSet`, so I think the simplification makes sense.

How to do it?

Comment: Although the C++ standard specifies a formal declaration of `std::set`, and other containers, like `std::vector` individual C++ implementation are free to follow the "as-if" rule. For example, a given C++ implementation is free to define `std::vector` as an alias: `template<typename T, typename A> using vector=vectorv1<T,A>`, and other things of this sort. This is frequently done to support multiple ABIs by the same compiler. In short, this kind of a forward declaration cannot be done in a portable manner. It won't work.

Comment: You are also running a foul of adding things to namespace std.  You're only allowed to specialize class templates for your own type in C++20 and beyond.

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks, I don't think it pollutes the namespace std, because it is just a forward-declaration, isn't it?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks, I'm not sure that I have got your point. Are you meaning that it is not a portable manner? i.e. it maybe works for gcc, but not for vc++?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 3):

One of the purposes of namespaces is to separate code that comes from different sources. This is often thought of avoiding name conflicts, but it goes to a deeper level.

When a library defines a namespace, it (typically) claims total possession of it. The library reserves the right to change any and all aspects of everything defined in the namespace, usually guaranteeing only the public API. This extends to forward declarations. Any forward declarations in the namespace are the library's domain unless stated otherwise, as the library may want to change things behind the scenes. Some libraries take this seriously and provide forward-declaration headers, but without those, you are out of luck.

In general, do not expect to be able to forward declare anything you do not control. Even if it works initially, it is liable to break at any upgrade/patch to the library.

---

Moving on to `std::set`, the `std` namespace is reserved for the standard library. The standard library grants you the ability to declare a few things in the `std` namespace in restricted circumstances, but otherwise it is off-limits to you. Unfortunately for your goal, the standard library does not require forward-declaration headers. If you want your code to be cross-platform and/or stable after a compiler upgrade, you will need to include the full header.

Going on a tangent: this is the basis for specifying that adding your own definitions to `namespace std` is undefined behavior. It's not that such things are guaranteed to break something, but that the language standard cannot guarantee what exactly will break things. (Realistically, if you were to define a class named `supercalifragilisticiwillmisspellthis` in `namespace std`, probably nothing will blow up.) To keep things simple, the "undefined behavior" label is applied and implementations are given maximum freedom.