# Why does C++ forbid forward declarations of non-template std:: types?

Tags: c++, c++20, forward-declaration

The C++ standard [does not allow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27642638/700825) code to forward declare classes in namespace `std`, even when they are not templates.

I see no good reason to do this, so I wonder what is the motivation?

It could be a huge compile time improvement. For example `std::mutex` is a simple class, but the `<mutex>` header drags in a ton of stuff (at least on my implementation).

If somebody wonders why I am making a distinction between templates and non-templates, then it is because template instantiations can differ significantly based on what template arguments are provided, so I guess that might be trickier to implement/support.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62420613/how-to-forward-declare-stdset-in-c

Comment: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/034.htm

Comment: Those types might be aliases...

Comment: @Jarod42 you mean like std::string is a typedef for basic_string<char>?  I am fine with banning those alseo. But I guess there are some types that are really not templates in std::

Comment: @vll Herb certainly has a sense of humor, at least when read in 2021 ". Fortunately, forward-declaring string and ostream isn't too much of an issue in practice since they're generally small and widely-used. The same is true for most standard headers."

Answer (score 6):

> for example `std::mutex` is a simple class

How do you know? The standard describes it as a class, but nothing is stopping an implementer from doing

```
namespace std {
    using mutex = _Internal_detail::_PthreadMutex;
}
```

Granted, I omitted some (likely very verbose and expert friendly) checks for when this alias should be set. But this is a valid implementation technique!

Now if you add your forward declaration, you will get an error since an alias and a class are different things. That makes such forward declarations inherently non-portable, and as such, they are deemed to produce undefined behavior.

Comment: I hate myself for asking this, but why would standard describe it as a class, and then allow alias. Is there no requirement that stuff that is specified as a class be implemented as a class?

Comment: I know about asif rule, but this seems to be not that, adding restrictions on use.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl - `_Internal_detail::_PthreadMutex` *is* a class, with all the behavior described by the standard. But there is no requirement that the name `std::mutex` be a class itself. The synopsis page is exposition, not a hard requirement. Standard library implementation is hard enough as it is. By forcing `std::mutex` to be a class proper, the standard may be imposing difficulties on implementers. And it doesn't want that, because C++ without happy implementers is a dead language.